# Bug reporting tool not working - what do I do?

Tags: bug-reporting, apport

I want to report a bug in a desktop application package (tomboy) in 18.04. Following the [guide on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), in a terminal window I issue `ubuntu-bug tomboy`. (This actually calls apport-gtk on my system.) A progress bar window appears telling me that information is being collected. After a while, a new dialog with the collected information appears, offering the buttons "Don't send" and "Send". When I click any of these, nothing happens.

According to the above linked site, a browser window should open, asking me to log in to Lauchpad, and describe the bug. I never get to this point. I observe the same behaviour when I try to report on other packages, just as a test. So it seems to me that the bug-reporting mechanism is broken, at least on my system.

What can I do to report the bug (the original one as well as the one in apport)?

Comment: That stuff has never worked for me either. Just go to the [launchpad bug pages for tomboy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy) and manually enter the bug yourself. Perhaps check the existing bugs first, to see if one already exists for your issue. If yes, then just add to it instead.